# EXCEL VBA: Comparing two columns and deleting a row if duplicate

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare a list from Column C with a list commencing at cell Y1001, and then where a duplicate exists, I want to delete the entire row of the duplicate from column C.

My code, however, is not producing this result!
Where is my error?

Thanks!

```
Sub Button3_Click()

'run comparison'

'Turn off screen updating to speed up macro'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim iListCount As Long
Dim x As Variant
Dim iCtr As Long



' Get count of records to search through (list that will be deleted)'
iListCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through the "master" list'
For Each x In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Y1001:Y" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
   ' Loop through all records in the second list.
   For iCtr = iListCount To 1 Step -1
      ' Do comparison of next record'
      If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 1).Value Then
         ' If match is true then delete row.
         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 1).EntireRow.Delete    
       End If
   Next iCtr
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

additional info:

I get "runtime error 424: object required'

When I run the debug the error line is:

```
If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 1).Value Then
```

But I'm failing to spot my error.

Comment: too broad. Do you get an error?

Comment: oops- sorry! I meant to put that.

I get "runtime error 424: object required'

When I run the debug the error line is:

      If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 1).Value Then

But I'm failing to spot my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a quick scan.
This code:

```
If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 1).Value Then
```

compares value of your `Y` to `A` and not `C`.
should be like this instead.

```
If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 3).Value Then
```

Comment: Thanks. 
I'd previously had the data in column A and forgot to transcribe across. Amazing the speed with which a fresh set of eyes picks the problem.
Much appreciated :)

Comment: i updated my answer :) I test and `Dim x as Variant` works as well as `Dim x as Range` my bad. glad it help you though. :)